# await a Task with a loop who await too

Tags: c#, async-await

first of all thanks for reading.
I'm here because in one of my project, i'm receiving packet continuously in a loop but when i close my app i'm getting a ObjectDisposedException from my ReceivePackets method who is called in ReceiveLoop, so i was like ok, i just have to wait until the _receiveTask is completed before closing my stream and tcp client but my _receiveTask return as completed without even reaching the end of the method.

I've tried using a Thread instead but same problem

Starting the task

```cs
if (_receiveTask == null)
{
    _receiveTask = Task.Run(new Action(ReceiveLoop));
}
```

Loop in the task

```cs
private async void ReceiveLoop()
{
    while (_client.Connected && _run)
    {
        await ReceivePackets();
    }
}
```

Receive packets task

```cs
private async Task<List<Packet>> ReceivePackets()
{
    var bytes = new byte[_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int size = await _stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    List<Packet> packets = Decrypt(bytes, size).Select(p => new Packet(p)).ToList();
    foreach (var packet in packets)
    {
        Dispatch(() => PacketReceived?.Invoke(packet));
    }
    return packets;
}
```

Stop method used

```cs
public async Task Stop()
{
    if (_client.Connected)
    {
        _run = false;
        await _receiveTask;
        _stream.Close();
        _client.Close();
    }
}
```

In the Stop method the _receiveTask is considered as completed but when i put a print something after the while loop in my ReceiveLoop, it's not even printed.

Comment: avoid using `async void`, and also you should do some reading on `CancellationToken` as they relate to `Task`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `ReceiveLoop` actually "returns" before all of its code complete, just like most `async` methods do. You need to make it return a `Task` and then await that instead of creating a new `Task` based on that action.

```
private async Task ReceiveLoop()
{
    while (_client.Connected && _run)
    {
        await ReceivePackets();
    }
}
```

...

```
_receiveTask = ReceiveLoop();
```